# creating membership with telerik openacces ORM and

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-open-access

I want to made a simple membership system for my application using altairiswebsecurity.codeplex.com

I use telerikopenaccess and I am not sure how this can help me.

someone please help me from this http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/getting-started-with-openaccess-overview.html

EntityDiagrams.rlinq but now I am not sure what is the next step to implemented it for my own project.

Answer (score 1):

There is however a fully implemented provider with the old OpenAccess API which you can find [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/orm/classic/complete-implement-telerik-orm-membership-provider.aspx). The general approach is the same, the context is just a wrapper around the IObjectScope used in the sample, so you can take the ideas from there and implement them on your side. As for the place where the membership provider should live into, it is up to you to decide where you find it more convenient, App_Code of another place in your application. From OpenAccess perspective this does not have any impact.